# Warning C4133 - Incompatible types

Tags: c

I'm writing a simple program, and I keep getting a C4133 error, but I can't find the problem. I did similar tasks in this way before and it worked perfectly without any errors. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

typedef struct dan {
    char ime[10];
    char stage[10];
    int posetioci;
    int dan;
    struct dan *sled;
}Dan;

Dan *ucitavanje(FILE* input) {
    Dan* glava = NULL, * tek = NULL, * temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(Dan));

    while (sscanf(input, "%c %c %d %d", temp->ime, temp->stage, &temp->posetioci, &temp->dan) == 4) {         
    // ^ This is line that gets error


        if (glava == NULL) {
            glava = temp;
            tek = glava;
        }
        else {
            tek->sled = temp;
            tek = tek->sled;
            tek->sled = NULL;
        }
        temp = malloc(sizeof(Dan));
    }
    return glava;
}


int main() {
    FILE* input = fopen("egzit.txt", "r");
    if (!input) exit(1);

    Dan* glava = ucitavanje(input);

    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is C4133 error? On what line does it happen?

Comment: here is the declaration of the ```sscanf``` function ```int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)```, as you can see your ```input``` type is ```FILE*```, so it is obvious that the compiler complaining about the pointer type

Comment: Post the file contents.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I wrote it in the code, read about C4133 online

Comment: @whoami Thank you, your comment helped me notice, it's not supposed to be sscanf, but instead fscanf. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your input string of chars is overflowing into your integer inputs.  `%c` will only account for a single character, try `%s` instead.

```
sscanf(input, "%c %c %d %d", temp->ime, temp->stage, &temp->posetioci, &temp->dan)
```

Comment: Yep, thank you, but that wasn't the reason why I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found mistake, it's not supposed to be sscanf but instead fscanf.